# Proper Design for an Entity with a Variable Number of Properties

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am implementing a custom form designer. I'm now to the point where I want to persist the layout to the database.

#### Technology Limitations

- .NET 4.0
- NHibernate
- Fluent NHibernate
- MSSQL 2008 R2

Here is a design I have come up with:

### Controls Table

- Id int identity
- Type varchar(300)

### ControlProperties Table

- Id int identity
- ControlId int FK to Controls.ID
- Name varchar(300)
- Value varchar(max)

### Control Class

```
public class Control
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Type { get; set; }
  public virtual Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I would then map this so I could do **something** like this to reload the layout:

```
var controls = GetListOfControlsUsingNHibernate();
foreach (var control in controls){
  var newControl = CreateControlFromType(control.Type);
  SetPropertiesViaTypeDescriptor(newControl, control.Properties);
  this.Controls.Add(newControl);
}
```

I have two questions.

1. How would one map this using Fluent NHibernate?
2. Is there a better approach that doesn't involve EAV and storing all values as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bud on twitter pointed me in the right direction for mapping this using Fluent NHibernate:

First create a table named `Properties` to hold our properties:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ ControlId ║ PropertyName ║ PropertyValue ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Now change our mapping like this:

```
public class ControlMap : ClassMap<Control>
{
    public ControlMap()
    {
        Table("Controls");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Type);
        HasMany(x => x.Properties).Table("ControlProperties")
            .AsMap<string>(index => index.Column("PropertyName").Type<string>(),
                           element => element.Column("PropertyValue").Type<string>())
            .Cascade.All(); 
    }
}
```

For some background on the hbm xml behind this see Ayende's [NHibernate Mapping Map](http://ayende.com/blog/4045/nhibernate-mapping-map).

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative ways to do that.

One solution is to use inheritance

```
public abstract class Control
{
    // ...
}
public class TextBox : Control
{
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
public class MaskedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public virtual string Mask { get; set; }
}
```

Another is to use different kinds of properties

```
public class Control
{
  public virtual ISet<Property> Properties { get; set; }
} 
public abstract class Property
{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public class IntProperty : Property
{
  public virtual int Value { get; set; }
}
public class DecimalProperty : Property
{
  public virtual decimal Value { get; set; }
}
// ...
```

Yet another is to use interfaces

```
public abstract class Control
{
}
public class TextBox : Control, ITextControl
{
  public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}


public class ConcreteControlMap<T> : SubclassMap<T> where T : Control
{
  public ConcreteControlMap()
  {
    if(typeof(ITextControl).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
      Map(c => ((ITextControl)c).Text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I create different types of properties how could I map that?

Comment: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#wiki-subclasses